# 7za: Reask password if wrong

Tags: 7-zip, 7za

I'm trying to extract a single file via a bash script with 7zip from a big container.

Command: `7za e archive.zip singlefilename`

If the password is wrong 7zip creates an empty file called `singlefilename` and the script proceeds which is not intended.

Is there any switch to reask passwords if they are wrong with 7za? Works smoothly with unzip :/

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please click on the checkmark underneath the answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Exit Code

Same as [Axel](https://superuser.com/users/190970)'s answer, but (since you mentioned bash) here's some bash code to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXIT=1
while [ ! $EXIT -eq 0 ]
do
        # 7-zip stuff
        EXIT=$?
done
```

---

When most programs finish without any errors, they set the exit code to `0`.

Testing for a non-zero exit code is often a good way to detect when a program failed in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you enter a wrong password, `7z` will return a non-zero `ERRORLEVEL` to the calling shell.

This can be used to launch a retry as follows in a `.cmd` script:

```
:again
::   -y  allows overwrite of existing file
7z.exe e -y xxx.zip "xxx.txt"
if errorlevel 1 goto try_again
echo. got it!
goto xit

:try_again
echo. sorry! Try again ...
goto again

:xit
```

**Note:**
The stand-alone version `7za` is not present [in all installations](http://www.ztw3.com/forum/forum_entry.php?id=114303).